# No sound on boot w/ speakers & headphones plugged in

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, sound-card, speakers

When I boot my pc with speakers + headphones plugged in, they're detected but don't play sound.

When I test them, they show that they're playing sound, but I don't hear anything.

The strange thing is, my sound will immediately work when I replug the speakers or headphones.

Another thing I found out was when I unplug the speakers, boot, then plug the speakers in when all the drivers have loaded (right after the windows boot screen) the sound works.
Any time before that, and there is no sound.

Specs:

- Windows 7 HP x64 (Yes I have the x64 driver)
- Alienware A08
- Realtek High Definition Audio (rtkvhd64.sys v6.0.1.6873)

Comment: Also, if I replug my headphones, the speakers work.